# Pre-Configuring Firefox for users on a Citrix Desktop Environment

Tags: citrix, firefox, xendesktop, mozilla

Is there a way to pre-configure firefox with the necessary bookmarks, configurations, and security settings for all users when they open it for the first time? If I could get a detailed guide or a link to an existing one that would be amazing.

Also any other recommendations for a pre-config would be great.

E.G. I need to enable/configure the following

- network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris
- network.negotiate-auth.allow-non-fqdn
- security.certerrors.mitm.auto_enable_enterprise_roots
- security.enterprise_roots.enabled
- Add a series of bookmarks in the bookmarks toolbar

Answer (score 0):

The initialization shortcut should include a script that copies a master profile over to the user's profile.  Mozilla Firefox saves profiles under this location:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
```

Next, copy the profiles.ini file from the parent directory:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini
```

You can edit this file to specify the profile that is engaged when a user selects the Firefox icon.